# ItemsSource as DataView binding with null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I made my own control that inherits from DataGrid to have a property named CurrentView witch is set in the event ItemsChanged I just set my property like

```
if (ItemsSource is DataTable)
        {
            CurrentView = ((DataTable)ItemsSource).DefaultView;
        }
        else if (ItemsSource is DataView)
        {
            CurrentView = ((DataView)ItemsSource);
        }
```

But sometimes when the datagrid is loaded my property takes the value but in my viewmodel in the property that is binded to CurrentView I get null. What is happening ? why if I set my CurrentView correctly I get null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some of the things that you could check:

1. Making sure CurrentView is a dependency property, to allow data binding
2. Making sure the binding is a Two way binding

Comment: I think that was the problem. I had it like binding.mode = TwoWay but for some reason it did not work. I just used like OneWayToSource, thanks